# How do you get app engine cron jobs to show in "scheduled tasks" tab on the web interface?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, cron, google-bigquery

I've been building an application to move google analytics data from Bigquery's datasets to Google Storage.

My intention is to deploy a web application on Google App Engine and set up a few cron jobs to call the right URL's periodically and then have some servlets to manage those requests.

I am developing on eclipse and using the App Engine plugin provided by Google here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/ .

Using this plugin, I have created a "Maven-based Google App Engine Standard Java Project", containing a simple java servlet HelloAppEngine.java, a basic index.jsp page and a class with a simple method. Here's the code for this three, the web.xml and the appengine-web.xml as well.

HelloAppEngine.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().println("Hello App Engine!");

  }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="bigqueryexport.HelloInfo" %>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marmelad' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Hello App Engine Standard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello App Engine -- Standard!</h1>

  <p>This is <%= HelloInfo.getInfo() %>.</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Available Servlets:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='/hello'>The servlet</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloAppEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bigqueryexport.HelloAppEngine</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloAppEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And finally, the appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

To this point, i have written not a single line of code and everything works just fine when I deploy this code to Google Platform. Now, according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron , by just adding a cron.xml file with the right code and deploying the app again, it should be ready to go. Here's the cron.xml that I have created in the same folder where appengine-web.xml is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/hello</url>
    <description>test cron job</description>
    <schedule>every 3 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

According to the documentation provided above, this should create the scheduled task that does a get request to my servlet every 3 minutes, yet when I deploy the application again, the cron job won't show on the google platform interface, and it won't work every 3 minutes either.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

PS: This is what the compilation outputs on the console.

> Beginning interaction for module default... 0% Scanning for jsp files.
>   0% Compiling jsp files. abr 04, 2017 4:34:24 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC
>   processFile INFORMACI�N: Built File: \index.jsp warning: [options]
>   bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7 Success.
>   Temporary staging for module default directory left in
>   D:\somepath
>   You are about to deploy the following services:
>    - project-id/default/20170404t163438 (from [D:\somepath\app.yaml])
>        Deploying to URL: [https://project-id.appspot.com]
>
> Beginning deployment of service [default]... File upload done.
>   Updating service [default]... .............................done.
>   Deployed service [default] to [https://project-id.appspot.com]
>
> You can stream logs from the command line by running:   $ gcloud app
>   logs tail -s default
>
> To view your application in the web browser run:   $ gcloud app browse

Comment: I just tried the steps you did and it shows up in my Cloud Console under App Engine > Task Queues > Cron jobs. Dummy question: have you re-run deploy after creating the cron.xml? Did you see in the deploy console a line like `Uploading cron jobs.`?

Comment: Check both methods of uploading cron jobs - occasionally uploading the entire app doesn't upload the cron jobs (or at least in python it didn't while the `update_cron` one did). https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#upload-cron

Comment: did you check the created war file? does it contain the cron.xml file? which sdk version are you using?

Comment: I edited the question to show how it looks on the console when i deploy using the eclipse plugin. The war file created in the target folder does contain the cron.xml file.

Comment: If I deploy using the mvn appengine:upload command it does upload the cron jobs as well. Is the plugin malfunctioning?

Comment: Can you clarify which plugin do you use? Is it the (old) Google Plugin for Eclipse (referred on developer.google.com/eclipse) or the (new) Cloud Tools for Eclipse (referred on cloud.google.com/eclipse)? If it's the latter, then this was a bug, and the new version (1.0.2) fixing it has just been released, so please update.

Comment: I am using the "Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.0.2" downloaded via the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: One more thing to check: when you make the deploy, is the checkbox for `Include optional XML configuration files` selected in the deploy dialog?

Comment: I solved it by updating the Eclipse plugin. I still read the same "Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.0.2", but something has changed because now it does deploy cron jobs.
Thank you everybody

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI as a work around you can find the cron.yaml file in your {buildOutputPath}/appengine-staged/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/ directory.

gcloud app deploy --project=yourprojectname cron.yaml will deploy the cron jobs to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are using at least the 1.0.2 version of the Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin which contains the fix for this problem. For reference: the relevant issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1676 and the relevant PR: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/pull/1690